# Is the Teams support email dead?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, email

A few hours ago, a [couple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/339846/4) of [edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/18233/16) were made to some posts on Meta Stack Exchange to remove mentions of the Teams support email address, `teams-support@stackoverflow.com`, and replace it with references to the Teams ticket portal.

Is this email address permanently closed? Will emails sent to it no longer reach the Teams support team? Or is filing a ticket on their site simply the *preferred* way to request help with Teams?

(Filing a Teams support request now requires one to create a separate account on an Atlassian server, which involves giving data to Atlassian, which wasn't required in the past. Some users may not want to do so, so I'm asking this.)

Comment: Regarding your parenthesized text: it *was* always required. In order to respond to tickets, we must create a user for them by inserting their email address into the system, which inherently creates an account even if they never set it up for logging in. No account = no reply.

Comment: @animuson In that case, the current model seems better, since they're told of the fact that Atlassian's getting their info, whereas they weren't told of this in the past.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None of the support e-mail addresses were removed, but we've since launched support via Intercom in the product. This is the best way to reach us for Teams support.